# std::find 'error no matching function'

Tags: c++, algorithm, header, find

Say that I have a class A and a class B that look like that:

```
Class A
{
private:
    int a;
public :
bool operator==(const A &) const;
//other methods(...)
}

Class B
{
private:
std::vector<A> v;
public:
std::vector<A> &get_v() {return v;};
const std::vector<A>& get_v() const;
}
```

Now when I do that:

```
B b;
std::vector<A>::iterator it;
it=std::find (b.get_v().begin(), b.get_v().end(), an item of class A);
```

The error I get is

```
error: no matching function for call to 'find(std::vector<A>::iterator, std::vector<A>::iterator, A&)
```

Am I missing something ? Thanks

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You forgot to `#include <algorithm>`.

Comment: Yes I figured it out! Thanks

Comment: Nice, cryptic C++ error messages. Instead of saying, that std::find cannot be found (because of missing include),  it says template argument deduction/substitution failed.

Comment: @Nuclear The point is that **an** `std::find()` can be found, but it's an overload with a different signature from a different header, which is not the one the OP was looking for. C++ is perfectly correct to complain in this case that the passed arguments do not enable resolution to any declared overload. If the cause were that _"std::find cannot be found"_, then the error would be _"std::find was not declared in this scope"_ or suchlike.

Comment: When I saw this, I was like yeah right... Let me just check-- then woah it was true! :)

Answer (score 12):

I think you forgot include header `<algorithm>`

Answer (score -6):

You forgot include this header file

```
#include<vector>
```

.

Comment: This is not the solution!