# Unexpected Unqualified Id before

Tags: c++

Unexpected unqualified - id before long
Unexpected unqualified - id before double
Unexpected unqualified - id before const

These are the errors I am receiving on the following code.

```
CreditCard::long long number() const {
return cardnumber;
}

CreditCard::double balance() const {
return cardbalance;
}

CreditCard::const char* name() const {
return cardname;
}
```

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: the return types should be placed before `CreditCard::` so it looks like `long long CreditCard::number() const { return cardnumber; }`

Comment: WTH?! Why don't people read the rule book before jumping into the lake of fire?

Answer (score 1):

you need `return_type ClassName::member_name(args) cv qualifier`:

```
long long CreditCard::number() const
```

etc.

Comment: @KerrekSB There's free rep? I've been overpaying!

Comment: @KerrekSB I couldn't find the duplicate. Anyway, I hit the max already, so this is rep-free answering :-)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: Sure, there's tons: Find a question about a trivial mistake, be the first [to post an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21609531/596781), profit. The feeling of dying a little on the inside will stop being annoying after a while.

Answer (score 1):

The return type goes before the class name,

```
long long CreditCard::number() const {
  return cardnumber;
}

double CreditCard::balance() const {
  return cardbalance;
}

// This should probably return a std::string
const char* CreditCard::name() const {
  return cardname;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The return types need to be specified before the class name

```
double CreditCard::balance() const
```